# slickgrid on cell change get focus and lock in activecell untill you enter valid data

Tags: javascript, jquery

It focus to cell and when I click outside cell, it returns `null("")` value when I click on grid after entering invalid data.

I need to get focus and lock in cell until user enters a valid email address.

Comment: if (!ValidateEmailAddress(item.ContactInfo)) {
                        $(currentCell).trigger('focus');
                        $(currentCell).addClass("invalid");
                        $(currentCell).stop(true, true).effect("highlight", { color: "red" }, 300);
                        args.grid.gotoCell(args.row, 2, true);
                         return false;

Comment: it focus to cell and when we click outside cell returns null("") value when we click on grid after entering invalid data I need to get focus and lock in cell until you enter valid email